# Unable retrieve session value in view in codeigniter

Tags: php, session, codeigniter-3

I have session variable on `gear.php` view as

```
$_SESSION['dbRecords'] = $product_number;
```

but when I go to different view eg. order.php, I am unable to retrieve value using

```
$product_number = $_SESSION['dbRecords'];
```

`order.php` loads on submit.

I am using CodeIgniter 3.

How can I get the value of `$_SESSION['dbRecords']`?

Answer (score 0):

You should get session data via Codeigniter style

setting data to session

```
$this->session->set_userdata('dbRecords', $product_number);
```

and get data from sessio

```
$dbRecord = $this->session->userdata('dbRecords');
```

I am not sure, the way you are doing is OK.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But that was a typo I corrected it now in the question.

Comment: Have you loaded Session library ?

Comment: yes, I have loaded library. I even crossed checked my code there is nothing wrong. It's something weird.

Comment: hmm yup weird. 

if you can share the access or that file to me ?

Answer (score 0):

i think you are not loaded `session` library

add session library in autoload

**application/config/autoload.php**

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('session');
```

OR

load  in controller `__contruct()` function

```
$this->load->library('session');
```